# Matrices of linear transformations relative to a basis

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm trying to solve this linear algebra problem and I wanted you to check if I'm doing the first one correctly and I need help in the second one. Here's the problem and my solution to the first part:

Let $E=\lbrace e_1,e_2,e_3 \rbrace$ be the standard ordered basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $B=\lbrace u,v,w \rbrace$ be an ordered basis formed by $u,v$ and $w$. Let $G (x,y,z)=xu+yv+zw$ be a linear transformation $G: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$. 1) Find the matrix of $G$ in the base $E$ (in the domain) and $B$ (in the image). 2) Do the same for the base $B$ (in the domain and the image).

The first part is easy, since $G(e_1)=G(1,0,0)=1\cdot u+0\cdot v + 0 \cdot w$, $G(e_2)=G(0,1,0)=0\cdot u + 1 \cdot v + 0\cdot w$ and $G(e_3)=G(0,0,1)=0\cdot u + 0\cdot v +1\cdot w$. Thus, the matrix of $G$ in the base $E$ (in the domain) and $B$ (in the image) is $A=\begin{pmatrix} [G(e_1)]_{B},[G(e_2)]_B,[G(e_3)]_B\end{pmatrix}=I$, where $I$ is a $3 \times 3$ identity matrix. How about the second part? I can't find a matrix $A$ in this case because I don't know explicitly the vectors $u,v,w$ in the basis. Unless I write them explicitly as $u=(u_1,u_2,u_3)$, $v=(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ and $w=(w_1,w_2,w_3)$, but how can I work it from here? Any help you can give me will be appreciated.

Comment: You *do* need to write $u$, $v$, and $w$ explicitly, because the definition of $G$ requires you to know the expression of the vectors in their standard form. If $u=(u_1,u_2,u_3)$, then $G(\mathbf{u}) = u_1\mathbf{u}+u_2\mathbf{v} + u_3\mathbf{w}$, so that means that $[G(\mathbf{u})]_{B} = (u_1,u_2,u_3)^T = \mathbf{u}$... etc.

Comment: So, can I work from there be writing those vectors in that form, i.e, $u=(u_1,u_2,u_3)$, $v=(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ and $w=(w_1,w_2,w_3)$? Or do I have to find an explicit non-standard basis $B$ in order to find that matrix?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by "non-standard basis $B$"... notice what my calculations show: no matter what vector $\mathbf{u}$ is, the first column of the matrix of $G$ relative to the basis $B$ will be the vector $\mathbf{u}$. What are the second and third columns?

Comment: The second and third columns of that desired matrix are $[G(v)]_B=(v_1,v_2,v_3)^T$ and $[G(w)]_B=(w_1,w_2,w_3)^T$, respectively. So can I leave them expressed in that way?

Comment: Note what those vectors **are**: the first column is the vector $u$; the second columns is the vector $v$; the third column is the vector $w$. So a better way to express that matrix is to note that its columns are *precisely* the vectors in $B$.

Comment: I understand. I really appreciate taking your time to help and explain me that. Thank you very much!